# Difference between GET(), read_html(), getURL() in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rcurl, rvest, httr

I'm attempting to scrape a realtor.com for a project for school. I have a working solution, which entails using a combination of the `rvest` and `httr` packages, but I want to migrate it to using the `RCurl` package, specifically using the `getURLAsynchronous()` function. I know that my algorithm will scrape much faster if I can migrate it to a solution that will download multiple URLs at once. My current solution to this problem is as follows:

Here's what I have so far:

```
library(RCurl)
library(rvest)
library(httr)

urls <- c("http://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/Denver_CO/pg-1?pgsz=50", 
          "http://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/Denver_CO/pg-2?pgsz=50")

prop.info <- vector("list", length = 0)
for (j in 1:length(urls)) {
prop.info <- c(prop.info, urls[[j]] %>% # Recursively builds the list using each url
             GET(add_headers("user-agent" = "r")) %>%
             read_html() %>% # creates the html object
             html_nodes(".srp-item-body") %>% # grabs appropriate html element
             html_text()) # converts it to a text vector
}
```

This gets me an output that I can readily work with. I'm getting all of the information off of the webpages, then reading all of the html from the `GET()` output. Next, I'm finding the html nodes, and converting it to text. The trouble I'm running into is when I attempt to implement something similar using `RCurl`.

Here is what I have for that using the same URLs:

```
        getURLAsynchronous(urls) %>%
        read_html() %>% 
        html_node(".srp-item-details") %>%
        html_text
```

When I call `getURIAsynchronous()` on the urls vector, not all of the information is downloaded. I'm honestly not sure exactly what is being scraped. However, I know it's considerably different then my current solution.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Or maybe an explanation on how `getURLAsynchronous()` should be working?

Comment: What you're attempting is a ToS violation. It'd be great if schools taught ethics as well as tech stuff.

Comment: @hrbrmstr: do you know of any good teaching aids/documentation to understand this subject (scraping and ToS) better?

Comment: @hrbrmstr, how could you possibly know this?  The ToS indicate that users can do exactly what the OP is doing with permission.  How do you know this isn't the case?